# Basic doubt on clear and preset inputs

Tags: signal, clock, flipflop

I am having a basic doubt regarding the working of preset and clear inputs.

Consider these two figures:-

[image]

[image]

Here in figure 1, if clear is 0, then Q will be 0 from 1.

But if its active low signal as shown in figure 2 then if clear is 0, then it will be inverted and clear input will be 1. So how will the output Q be 0 if clear input =1 ? I think it should not be inverted so that we can directly pass the clear input which is 0 and get output Q as 0.

I am not able to understand the meaning of active low signal and it's use here. What is the actual meaning of active low signal ? Is it just like attaching a NOT gate for input or does it mean that circuit will be active for low inputs but the inputs remain the same and not get inverted?

Please help.

Comment: The meaning of "active low" and "active high" is discussed in my answer to [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329598/) just earlier today.

Comment: If I *assert* CLR it means "I want to **clear** the output". In this design, in order to do that we must apply a low voltage to the CLR input. So we say that CLR is an *active low* input (it is asserted when a low voltage is applied).

Comment: Also, remember that when engineers talk about their circuit, they're limited to what human language can express. So they might not always be 100% careful about distinguishing what "set to 1" or "asserted" or whatever means, and you have to figure it out from context. If in doubt, read the schematic. (This is why we always like schematics in questions about circuits).

Comment: @The Photon, Please answer my one doubt. In figure 1, if we give CLR=0, then we get Q=0. But in figure 2, If we give CLR=0, then it will be inverted and CLR=1. So how will CLR=1, give Q=0 ? I just want to know this.

Comment: I interpret figure 2 differently from you. I think by including the bubble on the CLR input, they're just being more clear that this is an active low signal, and the behavior is the same as the circuit in figure 1. Really, you need to have the truth/transition table for the gate to know what it's behavior is. The symbol might be sloppily drawn.

Comment: So does it just mean that circuit is active if CLR = 0 and CLR remains the same which is 0 and is not inverted ?. I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXoQ4WAQ0qk about preset and clear.

Comment: Often real human beings are not always be 100% careful about distinguishing what "set to 1" or "asserted" or whatever means, and you have to figure it out from context. In this case I'd guess they mean that CLR is an active low signal, like in figure 1. If I was putting money on the line by basing a design around it that would cost money to build, I'd get a datasheet from the vendor and verify exactly what is the transition table for this device, not just try to guess from the symbol.

Comment: To me, figure 1 is the one that's wrongly labelled. In figure 1, CLR should have a bar over it or some other indication it's an active low signal.

Comment: Sir, I have seen this notation used almost everywhere where ever flip flops are used.  Even in that video same notation is used. In that video, you can just go to the end and see the truth table and diagram if you want.

Comment: I mostly do logic design for Xilinx FPGAs, and when they say "CLR" they mean an active high signal (see pg 175, [here](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx13_2/7series_scm.pdf), for example). Other vendors or environments may be different. Just make sure you understand the device/logic/library you are working with and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The signals are active low, because are inverted - the line above them is a inverting symbol. 
If CLEAR is 1, nothing happens, until it becomes 0, then the output is cleared.
If PRESET is 1, nothing happens, until it becomes 0, then the output is set.

Comment: I am sorry, I added the wrong picture before. Now I have edited the picture of SR flip flop. I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXoQ4WAQ0qk about preset and clear. In the edited figure of SR flip flop, how will CLR=0 to the flip flop give output Q as 0 ? Because after giving CLR=0, the input to the circuit will be value 1 which is equivalent to CLR=1.

Comment: @Zephyr Read my answer again if CLR=0, then Q=0. look the truth table from the video.

Comment: I figure 1, if we give CLR=0, then we get Q=0. But in figure 2, If we give CLR=0, then it will be inverted and CLR=1. So how will CLR=1, give Q=0 ?